# Grav's asset manager can fully replace a need for gulpjs?

Tags: gulp, grav

GravCMS has it's own asset manager: https://learn.getgrav.org/themes/asset-manager

It can minify, concatenate js/scss files.

Is it better to do such tasks via gulp (gulp-sass, gulp-concat, gulp-uglify), rather than using built-in asset manager in Grav?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't have any experience with the grav asset manager. But since you want to do grav-related tasks, I'd recommend to use the built in manager, as long as it can cover all your needs.

I don't see any benefit of using and adding an extra dependency in gulp/grunt or any other build tool.

The only time I'd consider using gulp is, if you already have an existing project with a gulp configuration and you can re-use it and have complex logic.

However probably you just want to minify/concatenate files. So the built in asset manager is the way to go

Comment: Asset manager can all kind of these tasks, except scss to css compilation :(

Comment: @AlexanderKim you can do the css compilation also in the terminal if you want. Maybe you can call/run a script from  the asset manager?

Comment: Well, running it every time i make a change to scss is annoying, so looks, like there's no way to omit gulp at all if i work with scss.

Comment: @AlexanderKim you don’t need to run it every time. There is a watch mode. Gulp ist just a wrapper. If you don’t need anything else there is no benefit in using gulp